# Google Cloud Artifact Registry Docker Storage pricing for images with Virtual size

Tags: google-cloud-platform, docker-image, google-artifact-registry

I have checked the documentation of AR and i see we have a storage cost mentioned as 0.1/GB per month for Docker images.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/pricing#storage)

However, docker has virtual size images and not actual size so does it matter in pricing of AR docker storage ? Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

Gcloud artifacts repositories list will give you the billed size of each repository.

The billed size will often be smaller than the sum of the image sizes because the same layer can be re-used in multiple images.

If you want to see how the billed size is determined, you can use gcloud artifacts files list to get a break down of the size per file (all files listed should sum to the billed size of the repo).